# flask api is not returning xml

Tags: python, xml, flask

I can't make my Flask API return XML.

I get no errors in the error log, but this is from the server log:

```
2020-06-10 21:14:01 [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>'
2020-06-10 21:14:01 [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>'
2020-06-10 21:14:02 DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 2) died :( trying respawn ...
2020-06-10 21:14:02 Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 13)
2020-06-10 21:14:02 spawned 2 offload threads for uWSGI worker 1
```

And from pythonanywhere I get this message:

## Something went wrong :-(

```
        <p>
            This website is hosted by PythonAnywhere, an online hosting
            environment. Something went wrong while trying to load it;
            please try again later.
        </p>

        <div class="for-site-owner">
            <h2>Debugging tips</h2>
            <p>
                If this is your PythonAnywhere-hosted site, and you just reloaded
                it, then the problem might simply be that it hasn&#39;t loaded up yet.
                Try refreshing this page and see if this message disappears.
            </p>

            <p>
                If you keep getting this message, you should check your site&#39;s
                server and error logs for any messages &mdash; you can view them
                from the Web tab inside PythonAnywhere.
            </p>

            <p>
                If there&#39;s nothing in the logs, and you&#39;re sure your site is OK,
                then it might be a problem on our side. Drop us a line at
                support@pythonanywhere.com, in the forums, or using the &quot;Send
                feedback&quot; link on the site, quoting the error code below.
            </p>
        </div>

        <p>
            Error code: 502-backend
```

Here is my code:

```
r = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

# get the xml from a json string

if r.status_code == 200:
    js_data = str(r.json)
    xml_data = readfromjson(js_data)
    return json2xml.Json2xml(xml_data).to_xml()
```

I can return js_data no problem

BR Kresten

Comment: I think you want `r.json()`, not `r.json`.  i.e. it's a method call, not a static attribute.

Comment: Also, it looks like `readfromjson()` expects a filename, not a json string.

Comment: I changed to r.json() and to readfromstring(), but it made no difference. Please se my resent edit

Comment: According to the code, you're still using `r.json` and `readfromjson()`.  What did you change?